# how to install the missing opencv module?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

This is for OpenCV 4.2.0, not sure about earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `opencv-contrib-python`

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```