# module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, face-recognition

## There is some of the code

```
import cv2 as cv
from cv2 import face
"""

bla, bla, bla ...

"""

face_recognizor = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizor.create()
```

**And it's throwing this error: **

face_recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

I'm using PyCharm btw.

***I already installed and imported: ***
opencv-contrib-python
face
face-recognizer

on PyCharm.

Also my Python and openCV version is = 3.11.5, 4.8.1

Comment: `pip list` and post the lines containing "opencv" -- you installed random modules that have nothing to do with opencv. don't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install the missing opencv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583284/how-to-install-the-missing-opencv-module)

Comment: also: ***typo***! did you notice that the identifier is "recognizer", not "recogniz***or***"? your code doesn't even match the error message. [mre] required. [tour], [ask], ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer) is the hint: install `opencv-contrib-python` **instead** of opencv-python (`pip install opencv-contrib-python`). I mean don't forget to uninstall the previous one.

Comment: It's all about of PyCharm. This code working on VSCode. Thanks for response Borden.